# 'extractIdentityAndTrust' error and warning while using code sample from certificate, key and trust programming guide

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, ios-4.2

I am trying to use the code from the 'Certificate,Key and trust programming guide'. In the section about extracting and evaluating an identity from a p12 file, I am getting error and warning from using the code given in the guide.

The line

```
status = extractIdentityAndTrust(inPKCS12Data, &myIdentity, &myTrust);
```

gives the warning: "Implicit declaration of function extractIdentityAndTrust "

while the function declaration of extractIdentityAndTrust"

```
OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inPKCS12Data,SecIdentityRef *outIdentity,SecTrustRef *outTrust)
```

gives me the error:conflicting types for extractIdentityAndTrust.

I am just trying to impement the code sample given in the guide. Please guide me where I am going wrong on this.

Comment: Im having this same problem. I am using code that i have found online. It uses the method "extractIdentityAndTrust(...)" but doesn't give implementation for it. Did you implement this method, or is it part of the framework?

Comment: If you are following Apple's guide to encryption/decryption, this method's implementation has to be given by you. In my case the error was resolved by declaring OSStatus extractIdentityAndTrust(CFDataRef inPKCS12Data,SecIdentityRef *outIdentity,SecTrustRef *outTrust); in the .h file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake!! didn't declare the method in the header file.